# How to differentiate tag popularity in a cloud tag?

Tags: language-agnostic

I never implemented a tag cloud before, so I have some ideas on how to do this. I was thinking of differentiating between them using CSS, and playing around with font sizes. But, how many CSS classes should I create? I can think of the following popularity "info":

- normal
- has some activity
- popular
- very popular

and use different font sizes for them. But, some websites seem to differentiate between them even more. Is my idea of differentiating tags bad? If I'd want to add more categories, I'd have to add more classes. Are there other ways of doing this that could be more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to name them. You can just create classes `popularity1` to `popularityX` where X is the number of differentials you want. You can adjust this number if you like. Just group the results differently and create extra css classes.

Alternative solution, although I wouldn't recomment this: You could nest classes with a relative font size, like 110%. For every higher popularity, you nest the elements one layer deeper.